# For what $n$ is the sequence consisting of the first $n$ digits of $\pi$ a palindrome

Tags: number-theory, pi

Can we find sequences of the first $n$ digits of $\pi$ so that this sequence is a palindrome, i.e $ 3,1,4, ...., 4,1,3$. Trivially, this is the case for $n=1$.

I say the following statement:
There are no such sequences other than the trivial case

Now, this statement is either true or false. I would bet my life on it to be true, but if it's true, could one ever prove so? I can be sure beyond any arbitrary level of doubt, but can we ever be completely sure. I think, no, because if such a sequence would exist it would just be a freak coincidence but nothing more. Thus, this statement is unprovable, demonstrating incompleteness. Humanity will never know the definitive answer to my question. Some things in math are true  but also uninteresting in nature. $\pi$ contains infinite information and we can state infinitely arbitrary conjectures about this information. We can't ever prove them, because they just don't really matter. They just are. And they just as well could not be, who knows? who cares?
Does my interpretation make sense or am I way off?

Comment: I mean I'm sure that there are no palindromes consisting of the first digits. We now the first billion zillion digits of pi, so if such a sequence exist it must be extremely large. The more digits we know, the less likely the existence of palindromes. Or do you disagree? If we agree, did you just misread it or is my formulation clumsy?

Comment: Terribly sorry, I missed the word "no"!

Comment: If such sequence exists it may be extremely short: $n=1$.

Comment: No worries! Now that we are on the same page, what are you thoughts about the statement in terms of provability or decidability?

Comment: Well, I don't expect that anyone currently has an idea on how to prove it.  We have not even proved that it is normal.  However, some clever person might come along with a great, new idea any day.

Comment: The question heavily depends on the base. In base 2 representation, pi is 11.001… You get palindromes for $n = 1$ and $n = 2$. The chances of finding a palindrome for larger $n$ also seem much better.

Comment: @AndroidBeginner I am not sure whether anyone has checked $\pi$ for palindromes so far. But this is not necessary anyway. If the first , say $200$ digits do not give such a palindrome , you can already "bet your life" on the truth of the conjecture. However , I agree that a proof of this is completely out of reach as it is to prove that $\pi$ contains every finite digit-string.

Comment: Do not make the error to mix things humans never know and incompleteness. Whether a computation is feasible in reality is irrelevant as long there is an algorithm doing the job. It can take Graham's number years and still a corresponding statement can be proven.

Comment: We cannot say "this statement is true" if we are not completely sure. Math is not a matter of probabilities , no matter how high. Noone will doubt this conjecture , but this does not mean that it must be true.

Comment: @Peter My point is that such a computation wouldn't take Graham number of years, but literally infinite years. In other words, it's not possible to determine whether the algorithm stops. That's my view at least

Comment: @AndroidBeginner I know and I agree.